# Enquire.js + Media.match + Respond.js

Tags: media-queries, enquire.js, respond.js

I'm trying to get Enquire.js working for legacy browsers. I'm using the Deep support method from the docs:

```
Modernizr.load([
    {
        test: window.matchMedia,
        nope: "media.match.min.js"
    },

    "enquire-2.0.0.min.js",
    "plugins.js", // jquery plugins
    "main.js" // enquire-triggered functions + general code
]);
```

The problem with this is I am using Modernizr+Respond from initializr.com, so the test always passes. This triggers a JS error in enquire.js in IE8/9.

By removing respond.js and just using plain Modernizr the test fails, Media.match loads, and the JS error is solved. However, I lose my Media Query support in IE8.

What's the best method to get everything working together? I have tried loading respond.js at the same time as Media.match via Modernizr. If I load it first, I see the same JS error as before. If I load it second, media queries don't work. I've also tried just loading that INSTEAD of Media.match, but the JS error returns.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Shortly after posting this I rolled back to enquire 1.5.6, used Respond.js, the shouldDegrade option, and no Modernizr tests. No JS errors in IE8/9, and everything seems to be working fine so far.

I am still interested to know if there's a way to get this working with 2.0, or if I should stick with the 1.5.6 for now?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem with Enquire v2.0.2. My workaround was to remove the inclusion of matchMedia from respond.js, and then load media.match and enquire.js after loading respond.js. I haven't tested this with modernizr yet, but I was able to get media query support and enquire.js to work in IE7 and 8 with no JS errors.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the actual problem is that in respond.js you do have the matchMedia polyfill but without the [matchMedia.addListener plugin](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/blob/master/matchMedia.addListener.js). So the modernizr test for plain matchMedia succeeds but then results in the error you probably get with enquire (Object doesn't support this property or method).

I myself wouln't like to customize respond.js not to include matchMedia but rather just load the matchMedia.addListener plugin separately after respond.js.

Answer (score 0):

Tim,

A little late but did you see this yet? I think it's what you are looking for.

[enquire.js legacy support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402932/enquire-js-legacy-support)

Comment: That's actually the thread that I started following to try fix this problem. I never did, though -- not with enquire 2.0. I always ended up with a JS error in one version of IE or another. I'm getting ready to tackle this on another site soon, so I'll probably give it another shot.