# Css3 media query polyfill

Tags: javascript, css

I'm looking for a great polyfill for Css media query  written in Javascript that works in any browser (IE > 7 at least).

There is something better than this? http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/

thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14403603/560287

Answer (score 1):

Modernizr has a list of polyfills at https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills I'm using Respond (https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) without any problems.